# Assign NULL to repeated values in different columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a table like this:

| id | mail_1 | mail_2 | mail_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | john_v2 | NULL |
| 2 | clarisse | clarisse | clarisse_company |
| 3 | NULL | julie | NULL |
| 4 | mark | markus_91 | mark |
| 5 | alfred | alfred | alfred |

And I would like to put NULLs where the mail is repeated, for example in the row 2 mail_1 and mail_2 have the same value; clarisse, and I would like to assign a NULL in mail_2. So I'm thinking in an algorithm that first fix the row and then go through the columns and check if the current value is the same as the previous. So the final table would be something like this:

| id | mail_1 | mail_2 | mail_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | john_v2 | NULL |
| 2 | clarisse | NULL | clarisse_company |
| 3 | NULL | julie | NULL |
| 4 | mark | markus_91 | NULL |
| 5 | alfred | NULL | NULL |

Doing this with other languages is pretty easy, such Python or R, but I would like to have it done in SQL.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: tag your dbms name please

Comment: I am using SQL-Server 18

Comment: There is no SQL Server 18, @Miquel . The latest version is version 15, aka SQL Server 2019. SQL Server 2022 comes out later this year, but that will likely be version 16. Version 18 likely won't be available until 2026 at the *earliest* (assuming Microsoft go back to a release every other year).

Comment: sorry, the version I am using is 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you could use `NULLIF`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       Mail1,
       NULLIF(Mail2,Mail1) AS Mail2,
       NULLIF(NULLIF(Mail3,Mail2),Mail1) AS Mail3
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Ideally, however, you should be normalising your design. Don't have 3 mail columns, have just one. If a "thing" can have multiple values for Mail, then you need 2 tables with a one to many relationship. If 2 "things" can have the same Mail as well, then you need 3 tables, so that you can define a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select id,mail_1,
case when mail_1=mail2 then null else mail_2 end as mail_2, mail_3
from table_name
```