# Fill columns which have priority over other columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns, fill

I have a table like this:

| id | mail_1 | mail_2 | mail_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | john_v2 | john_v3 |
| 2 | clarisse | NULL | clarisse_company |
| 3 | NULL | julie | NULL |
| 4 | mark | markus_91 | NULL |
| 5 | alfred | NULL | NULL |

And I would like to achieve that:

| id | mail_1 | mail_2 | mail_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | john_v2 | john_v3 |
| 2 | clarisse | clarisse_company | NULL |
| 3 | julie | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | mark | markus_91 | NULL |
| 5 | alfred | NULL | NULL |

As you can see, if mail_2 or mail_3 are not null and mail_1 is null, mail_1 should be fulfilled. The thing here is if the id has two mails, this two mails must be in mail_1 and mail_2, not in mail_2 and mail_3 nor mail_1 and mail_3. If an id has just one mail, this mail must be in mail_1.

So the logic here is that mail_1 has priority over the other two, and mail_2 has priority over mail_3.

How could I achieve that in SQL Server (version 15)?

Comment: I must ask, why not just fix your design and use a normalised table, like I mentioned in the answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71156538/2029983)? Then this is a non-issue (as the issue doesn't exist)

Comment: It's a little bit long to explain, but there are another tables that must be joined with this one throught the id, and the id must be the primary key. And there are a lot of tables where I have to join by the id, so my priority is to keep the id unique. And I don't wanna lost information about mails, if there are 3 mails I need the 3 mails, so I need to put them in columns to keep the id unique.

Comment: So what happens when someone inevitably needs 4 mails?

Comment: there are just 3 fields in the CRM to fulfill

Comment: That doesn't answer what happens when a 4th is needed though. Normalising your design looks to be the real solution here; then both this question and your prior one are moot as the problems don't exist.

Comment: but i cannot modify the original tables, I just can take them and do things with them but not redesign them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This should do. Just play by changing the values of the table variable below

declare @temp table(mail_1 varchar(20),mail_2 varchar(20),mail_3 varchar(20))

insert into @temp values(null,'middlename','lastname')

select coalesce(mail_1,mail_2,mail_3) as mail_1,
case when mail_1 
is null and mail_2 is not null then mail_3
when mail_1 
is not null and mail_2 is  null 
 then
mail_3 
else mail_2 end mail_2,
case when (mail_1 is null or mail_2 is null) then null else mail_3 end mail_3
from @temp
```